# Проверка группы Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу бота. http://forum.revent-rp.ru/index.php?/user/51595-bntz/ . Есть строчка "Группа" и её значение "Пользователи" как мне проверить что у юзера группа "Пользователи"?

Comment: Используйте lxml или Beautiful Soup, Selenium для этих целей слишком тяжелый

Comment: @danilshik Да я уже сделал